# Is there any significance to the two coins under the first bridge in Super Mario 64?

Tags: super-mario-64

I noticed that there are two coins under the first main bridge leading into the castle.  I am trying to side-flip and wall bounce to get them both, but do they have any use as I am not in a 'world' right now?

Comment: there are also 4 coins next to the main stairs that you can collect...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those coins, along with all the other coins you can find in the castle, have no significance, and you do not get a star for collecting them.

I believe at some point in development, there would have been a Star for gathering all 100 coins in the castle itself, but it was dummied out.

To get the coins anyway, see the spoiler below.

> You need to get all 120 stars and then blast your way to the roof with the cannon.  Up there, you will find Yoshi, as well as several Wing Cap blocks that you can use to fly around the castle area and gather the coins under the bridge.

Comment: He's talking about the coins under the bridge, not the ones on the roof.

Comment: I believe he means to fly to the coins after you get the cap

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about those coins.

Comment: Can the downvoter please comment on the downvote? Sure this answer is short and Zibbobz has provided a much more verbose answer; but it answers the question correctly, does not contain speculation, and does not provide information not asked for.